# Apns push run in main function is work ok,but run in tomcat is errors?

Tags: tomcat, jetty, apple-push-notifications

## Detail

I using  [notnoop java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns)  push mdm message,**I try in     main function push message is ok!** but add into spring mvm  run in jetty/tomcat web context throws javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure ! help me.

### using spring mvc method

```
ModelAttribute
RequestMapping("/deviceinfo")
public String pushCommand(HttpServletRequest request)
{
  String id = request.getParameter("id");
  Device device = deviceManager.get(new Long(id));
  log.debug(device);
  log.debug(device.getToken());
  ApnsService service = APNS.newService().withCert( ClassLoader
  .getSystemResourceAsStream("mdm_push.p12"),"123456")
  .withProductionDestination().build();
  String mdmPayload = APNS.newPayload().mdm(device.getToken().getPushMagic()).build();
  service.push(device.getToken().getToken(), mdmPayload);
  log.warn("mdmDeviceInfoCommand");
  return "device form";
}
```

### error message:

> INFO [Thread-19] ApnsConnectionImpl.run(170) | Exception while waiting for error code
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
>     at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
>     at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
>     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
>     at >com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl$1MonitoringThread.run(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:114)
>   DEBUG [qtp297885139-65] ApnsConnectionImpl.socket(218) | Made a new connection to APNS
>   INFO [Thread-20] ApnsConnectionImpl.run(170) | Exception while waiting for error code
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
>     at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
>     at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
>     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
>     at >com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl$1MonitoringThread.run(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:114)
>   INFO [qtp297885139-65] ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(264) | Failed to send message >Message(Id=1; Token=07BE34F5A71A; Payload={"mdm":"E101CB39-697A-4883-B303-67713DEE836E"})... >trying again after delay
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
>     at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
>     at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
>     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
>     at >com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl$1MonitoringThread.run(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:114)

Comment: Information not sufficient... Share the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably due to your tomcat server not being able to access the p12 file. Either you forgot to upload the p12 file to your server, or it's looking for it in a folder which is different than the one you put it in.

`.getSystemResourceAsStream("mdm_push.p12"),"123456")`

You should probably specify the path of the p12 file in that call.

Comment: Thinks！ getSystemResourceAsStream at web context is no work! but notnoop design is so bad!stream is 'null' no error Prompt!!!